# Questions about arguments of tikz macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, plain-tex

I'm a novice at coding. 
I'm reading the code of the macro `\tikz@scan@one@point`, 
but I have lots of troubles:

1. Question 1: 
   How to distinguish the arguments of a macro? For example 
   the definition of `\tikz@scan@one@point` has one parameter 
   (`\def\tikz@scan@one@point#1{...`), 
   if I type `\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(A)` 
   ("(A)" is a node in TikZ), then 
   which part of the code is the "`#1`" in the definition? 
   is that `\pgfutil@firstofone(A)`? or only the macro`\pgfutil@firstofone`?
2. Question 2: 
   macro `\tikz@scanexpand` has only one parameter (`\def\tikz@scanexpand#1{...`), 
   but in the definition of `\tikz@scan@absolute`, 
   the macro `\tikz@scanexpand` isn't followed by any arguments:

```tex
\def\tikz@scan@absolute#1{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar({\tikz@scan@@absolute#1}%)
  {%
    \advance\tikz@expandcount by -1%
    \ifnum\tikz@expandcount<0\relax%
      \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@scangiveup%
    \else%
      \let\pgfutil@next=\tikz@@scanexpand%
    \fi%
    \pgfutil@next{#1}%
  }%
}%
```

This phenomenon often occurs in TikZ and LaTeX source code.
Could Some body explain why ^_^?

if you have already read the source code of tikz, 
Could you explain the working principles of macro `\tikz@scan@one@point`? 
That would be very helpful for me.

And also, do you have any tricks of reading TeX source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that TeX works with tokens. and when grabbing an undelimited argument this will mean that we grab either

- One token or
- One *balanced text*: something inside braces*

- More formally, TeX absorbs everything after category code 1 token upto a matching category code 2 token, balancing any nested category code 1/2 pairs appropriately.

Thus when you use `\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(A)`, `\tikz@scan@one@point` takes just `\pgfutil@firstofone` as `#1`: we have no braced argument for a *balanced text*.

In `\tikz@scan@absolute`, what happens is that `\pgfutil@next` is set equal (`\let`) to the action to take: this can be `\tikz@@scanexpand` but could also be set equal to `\tikz@@scangiveup`. The token `\pgfutil@next` is then used followed by `{#1}`, so the argument to `\tikz@scan@absolute` *is* passed to `\tikz@@scanexpand` as a *balanced text*.

In general terms, you've got to think tokens, and remember that TeX works by macro expansion. Here, `\tracingall` is your friend, but start small - TikZ is complex and you could have literally millions of lines of tracing!